# Laravel Excel not downloading

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

This is what I have currently
Export class

```
class ReportExcel implements FromArray, withHeadings
{
use Exportable;

protected $items;

public function __construct(array $items)
{
    $this->items= $items;
}

public function headings(): array
{
    return ["Opcion 1", "Opcion 2", "Opcion 3", "Nombres", "Apellidos", "Telefono", "Correo",
        "Pais", "Pais Otro", "Edad", "Adventista", "Estudia la Biblia", "Peticion", "Fecha"];
}

public function array(): array
{
    return $this->items;
}
```

}

method in my controller

```
public function downloadExcel(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->country == null) {
        $item = Form::get(['option_1', 'option_2', 'option_3', 'name', 'lastname', 'phone',
            'email', 'country_id', 'country_other', 'age', 'adventist', 'study', 'petition', 'date_answered']);
    } else {
        $item = Form::where('country_id', $request->country)->orderByDesc('created_at')
            ->get(['option_1', 'option_2', 'option_3', 'name', 'lastname', 'phone', 'email', 'country_id',
                'country_other', 'age', 'adventist', 'study', 'petition', 'date_answered']);
    }

    $items[] = $item;

//   return (new ReportExcel($items))->download('invoices.csv', Excel::CSV,
//            ['Content-Type' => 'text/csv']);
    return Excel::download(new ReportExcel($items), 'reporte.csv');
}
```

I have tried both ways seen in my controller neither downloads anything I do see something like this, if I change the extension to `xls` or `xlsx` the data is unreadable as there are a ton on symbols that show up as well

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I get this to download an actual excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a `<a href=""/>` to the route instead of using the method as it doesn't work when sending the request through vue. The other code is correct.